# Javascript validation error with Google maps script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to upload some Javascript code, but the validator is not validating some Javascript code. I am not getting any hints, so I narrowed it down to the below lines.

The validator is in a backend validator, there is in a homemade CMS system. The only error I get is: "HTML error in input". But that message is global for all errors, so it is not very relevant for this javascript. (I did not make the CMS system..)

Can anybody see something that I cannot?

```js
   
for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
    map: map,
    title: locations[count][0]
  });
}
```

Comment: So where are you validating? And what is the error?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just updated my question with more details.

Comment: Where you trying to upload this code to?

Comment: I cannot publish the code. It is in a CMS system there has been build throughout the last 10 years. So nothing known.

Comment: Wild guess `< locations` is an opening html tag ?

Comment: I now narrow it down to this line: `for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) .`. So the validator would think `<` is an opening tag maybe. Is there another way to write the forloop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the < operator is the problem you can try this code:

```js
for (var count in Array.from(Array(locations.length).keys())) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
        map: map,
        title: locations[count][0]
      });
```